# How to check for dependencies with setuptools?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools

I am making a package that depends on `backports.lzma`. So I have something like this on my `setup.py`:

```
    install_requires=[
        "enum34", "hashlib", "backports.lzma",
        "termcolor", "xmltodict"
        ],
```

During my package installation ran with `python setup.py install`, I will get this error if `liblzma-dev` is not properly installed:

```
This is backports.lzma version 0.0.3
backports/lzma/_lzmamodule.c:115:18: fatal error: lzma.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The final user will hardly understand the cause of the error.

Is it possible to automatically check for third party software dependencies and prompt the user to install these dependencies?

Comment: A lot of scripts I installed via `pip` collected necessary packages first, so it's possible. But don't know how...